# jQuery - using addClass on specific window width with toggleClass on same element

Tags: jquery

i have a on resize add class jQuery function which help me show an element on a certain window size:

```
<div class="v-menu"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">b</a>
    <a href="#">c</a>
</div>
```

```
(function($) {
        var $window = $(window),
            $html = $('#menu');
        function resize() {
            if ($window.width() < 612) {
                return $html.addClass('close');
            }
            else{
            $html.removeClass('close');
            $html.removeClass('open');
            $('*[class=""]').removeAttr('class');
            }
        }
        $window
            .resize(resize)
            .trigger('resize');
    })(jQuery);
```

and i can toggle it with another function:

```
$(".v-menu").click(function(){
$("#menu").toggleClass("open");
$("#menu").toggleClass("close");
});
```

the problem is if i toggle the element to open **and then** resize the window jQuery keep adding the `close` class to the element:

```
<div id="menu" class="open close">
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">b</a>
    <a href="#">c</a>
</div>
```

how can i solve that?

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish? Right now when you resize the window and the window width is lower than 612, `.close` will always be added

Comment: Seems likes something you could do with an @media query in css.  Show/hide an element based on the window size.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @NiekNijland i dont want that `close` class add when the `open` class added.

Comment: Try: `if ($window.width() < 612 && !$html.hassClass('open')) {`

Comment: If you can sketch us an use case of what you are trying to accomplish maybe we can point you in another direction, because this doesn't really feel like a good solution of your problem :/

Comment: it is adding both class when window size is greater than 612. If size is  greater than 612, menu class don't  have open and close. but when you click v-menu, it will add both the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment

> i dont want that close class add when the open class added.

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
 if ($window.width() < 612){
         if(!$html.hasClass('open')) {
                  return $html.addClass('close');
         }
 }
```